# Is there a cross-browser event after all resources are loaded and rendered (even from cache)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

I am looking for a way to run code after all images on the page are loaded and rendered (not half-way but fully).

I found that window's `load` event should be a cross-browser event for when all of the content is loaded and parsed on the page, but I experience a problem where Safari on desktop and on mobile fire it too early (almost at the same time as the `DOMContentLoaded` document event) when the images are not cached, but work as expected when they are already cached.

Is there a cross-browser way to ensure all the images on the page are loaded and rendered and then run some code?

I am also thinking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/6123494) comment about `onload` window event suggesting that:

> In some browsers it now takes over the role of document.onload and fires when the DOM is ready as well.

I am not sure, if it is relevant, but I also found this caveat on the JQuery load event of images on the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK, thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Recommend removing the irrelevant thing from the jQuery docs about the `img` `load` event.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, mentioned that it may not be relevant

Comment: FWIW, I don't think there is any such event (but I can't say for sure). I would be surprised if responding to `window`'s `load` event with `setTimeout(function() { /* Do the work here */ }, 100);` didn't do the job, though, unless the page is **really** complex... :-)